# Space complexity Matrix form of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: algorithms

I read the following [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

That compute $F_n$ in $O(\log n)$, but i can't find the space complexity of this matrix form of $F_n$.

Comment: Welcome to COMPUTER **SCIENCE** @SE. How big is $F_n$ (the output)? (and what is the relation to • your question • the time complexity *you see claimed*?)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it self-contained, so we don't have to click on an external link to understand your question and we can still understand what is being asked even if the link stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm uses a constant number of $2 \times 2$ matrices which contain Fibonacci numbers $F_m$ for $m \leq n$, as well as a few indices ranging up to $n$.

This should be enough information to compute the space complexity of the algorithm, whether expressed in machine words or in bits.

As an aside, since $F_n$ grows exponentially in $n$, it is misleading to count only the number of arithmetic operations, rather than the bit complexity of the computation.

Comment: Why $F_n$ grows exponentially in $n$?

Comment: This follows from the closed-form expression $F_n = \bigl((\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n - (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n\bigr)/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Oh! Thank you, it's amazing... I spend so much times to find out why it's exponentially in $n$:)

Comment: So any methods such as DP,  is exponentially in $n$ for computing $F_n$?

Comment: The length of $F_n$ in bits is only linear in $n$.

Comment: Why you say it's linear? Also my teacher think like your, but i can't understand why we say linear while the algorithm work in $O(\log n)$?

Comment: The length of $F_n$ in bits has nothing to do with algorithms.

Comment: I figured out, because the input needs $\log n$ bits, and running time of algorithm is $\log n$, so the algorithm is linear. Thank you.

Comment: But the question is,  if $F_n$ grows exponentially, why we can compute it in $\log n$? While i think each cell of Matrix $2*2$ needs $n-$bits storage. So we must multiply $n$ and $\log n$. Is my argument is correct?

Comment: That's right, in practice it won't really take logarithmic time, since the numbers involved are so large.